# Reddit API in php returns bad captcha for submitting story

Tags: php, api, httprequest, reddit

Using php for Reddit api for submitting a story returns bad captcha as error.
I am able to login using the api and get usermod and captcha perfectly using api.
Ideally if the reddit_session cookie is passed it should post and not return bad captcha can someone shed me some light on this..

reference link: 
https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API

```
<?php
$user = "";
$passwd = "";
$url = "http://www.reddit.com/api/login/".$user;

$r = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->addPostFields(array('api_type' => 'json', 'user' => $user, 'passwd' => $passwd));

try {
    $send = $r->send();
    $userinfo = $send->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}

$arr = json_decode($userinfo,true);

$modhash = $arr['json']['data']['modhash'];
$reddit_session = $arr['json']['data']['cookie'];

$post = array('uh'=>$modhash,
               'kind'=>'link',
                'url'=>'yourlink.com',
                'sr'=>'funny',
                'title'=>'omog-asdfasf',
                'id'=>'newlink',
                'r'=>'funnyier',                
                'renderstyle'=> 'html'              
                );


$url = "http://www.reddit.com/api/submit";

// Upvote RoboHobo's comment :)
// Add user cookie data
$r->addCookies(array("reddit_session" => $reddit_session));
// Set URL to vote
$r->setUrl($url);
// Add vote information, found at http://wiki.github.com/talklittle/reddit-is-fun/api-all-functions
$r->setPostFields($post);
// Send request blindly


try {
    $userinfo = $r->send();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;   
}
pre($userinfo);
exit;

function pre($r){
echo "<pre />";
print_r($r);
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd LOVE to know the answer to this, having the same problem myself.  What's the point of CAPTCHA in an API?

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else that stumbled onto this question lately and is still having that issue:

The above issue was fixed and works correctly however if you created a new account for your reddit bot and try to submit a story you will recieve a bad_captcha error. New accounts have to submit captchas until they gain a certain amount of karma so this is the error you are seeing. Try the request with an older account and this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Took me forever to find this fix.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot get captcha link image so we can embed it into app so that user can solve inside app?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, at the moment CAPTCHA is broken in the Reddit API. They originally were using an outdated PyCAPTCHA and were [migrating to reCAPTCHA](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/pull/163). Since then, there has been an [issue](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/issues/262) with using `api_type:json` which has a work around and someone on github is currently working it. He also offered an explanation/solution:

> Quite simply, the json (though not jquery) result should contain the captcha_id when a >captcha is required. By captcha_id I mean the part to complete a url like the followng: >http://www.reddit.com/captcha/(captcha_id).png
>
> The use case I encountered is when trying to submit a story via the api using >api_type:json. I am nicely notified that my non-existent captcha is incorrect, however, I >then have to make a request to http://www.reddit.com/api/new_captcha in order to get the >captcha_id. This last round trip seems unnecessary.